# Convert Uint8ClampedArray to Image file as shown below and tell me solution

Tags: angular, image-processing, uint8array, image-file, imagedata

I want to convert Uint8ClampedArray (as shown in image):-
[image]

to an image file(as shown in image):-
[image]

I want this conversion so that I can send that image file to an API in angular

Comment: What does this API expect as an input?

Comment: It takes input as image file in form data

Comment: Have you solved this?